# What are the basics for notation used in cardinal arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

If $S$ and $T$ are sets, which of the following would you say is $T^{S}$?

- $T^{S}$ is the set of all functions from $S$ to $T$.
- $T^{S}$ is the Cartesian product of $T$ taken $\begin{vmatrix} S \end{vmatrix}$ times. That is, $\underbrace{T \times T \times \cdots \times T \times T}_{\begin{vmatrix} S \end{vmatrix} \text{ times}}$?

As a simple example, suppose that ...

> $T = \begin{Bmatrix} 0, 1 \end{Bmatrix}$.

---

If ...

> $T^{T}$ is $\underbrace{T \times \cdots \times T}_{\begin{vmatrix} T \end{vmatrix} \text{ times}}$

... then ...

> $T^{T} = \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0, 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0, 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1, 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1, 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$

---

However, suppose that $T^{T}$ is the set of all functions from set $T$ to set $T$.

Then $T^{T} = \{ f_{1}, f_{2}, f_{3}, f_{4}  \} $ where ...

$$
\begin{align}
f_{1} & = \{ (0, 0), (1, 0) \}    \\
f_{2} & = \{ (0, 0), (1, 1) \}    \\ 
f_{3} & = \{ (0, 1), (1, 0) \}    \\ 
f_{4} & = \{ (0, 1), (1, 1) \}    \\ 
\end{align}
$$

---

An answer to this question would explain the basic notation used for cardinal arithmetic and explain all of the notation given in the formula(s) below:

$$\begin{align}A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)&\cong(B\rightarrow C)^A
\\&\cong\left(C^B\right)^A
\\&\cong C^{A\times B}
\\&\cong(A\times B)\rightarrow C\end{align}$$

---

Is $\begin{pmatrix} B\rightarrow C \end{pmatrix}$ the set of all ordered pairs such that the left-most element in the pair comes from set $B$ and the right-most element in the pair comes from set $C$?

That is, $\begin{pmatrix} B\rightarrow C \end{pmatrix} = \begin{Bmatrix} (b, c) : b \in B \text{ and } c \in C\end{Bmatrix}$

For example, $\begin{pmatrix} B \rightarrow C \end{pmatrix}^{2} = \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} (b_{1}, c_{1}), (b_{2}, c_{2}) \end{pmatrix} : b_{1}, b_{2} \in B \text{ and } c_{1}, c_{2} \in C\end{Bmatrix}$

Alternatively, $\begin{pmatrix} B \rightarrow C \end{pmatrix}^{2} = \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} b_{1}, c_{1}, b_{2}, c_{2} \end{pmatrix} : b_{1}, b_{2} \in B \text{ and } c_{1}, c_{2} \in C\end{Bmatrix}$

In your explanation of the basics of the notation used for cardinal arithmetic you can assume that:

- we already know what a set is. For example **{ 1, 2, 3 }**
- We know what a set of ordered pairs is.  **{ (0, 1), (2, 1) }**
- We know what a Cartesian product of two sets is.
- What already know what cardinality is. $4 = \vert \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} \vert$ and there is no bijection between the set of all whole numbers $\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{N} \end{pmatrix}$ and the set of all decimal numbers $\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{R} \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your first question: $T^{S}$, where $T$ and $S$ are sets, is referred to as all functions $f: S \rightarrow T$. The cardinality of $T^{S}$ is equal to $|T|^{|S|}$, if all sets in a cartesian product are the same then $T^n = \underbrace{T \times T \times \dots T}_\text{n times}$. Which is not quite the same as $T^{S}$ where $T$ and $S$ are sets.

Here is a link for reference and some more reading if you'd like:
[Sets, Functions and Relations](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Emlerma/courses/cs310-05s/notes/dm-sets.pdf)